# Highslide Photo Gallery and External Databases

Tags: database, highslide

Is it possible to connect a highslide gallery to an external database that can load in the image/path/etc as well as the caption/text assoicated with that image into a website. Thereby eliminating the need to house the images, thumbs and html code on the page referencing the images specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, serving the images and captions etc. in a database is standard procedure for web developers working with server based technologies like PHP/MySQL, Node.js or ASP.NET. I won't go in detail here, but the idea is to make the server side language print HTML and JavaScript for the client, for example by printing image tags including the image file path and caption text. To learn about this in detail, you need to know the basics in for example PHP, which you can pick up in online resources on the matter.